# File System in Node js causing error

Tags: node.js, fs

fs.writeFile(); is causing problem when i uploading image. BTW image is uploaded but there is some server issue happening. like **502 Bad Gateway**
       and in putty i can see error message like " **Forever detected script was killed by signal: SIGKILL**"

short code :

```
fs.writeFile(userUploadedImagePath, imageBuffer.data, function(err ) {

        json_response['success'] = true;
        res.json(json_response);

      });
```

Comment: `SIGKILL` sounds like a situation where your server is killing your process (due to excessive memory use perhaps).

Comment: What is in the json_response object?  It maybe causing a problem when express is stringifying object in function.  Wrap it in a try catch and log the error.

Answer (score 2):

Try to log the error information:

```
fs.writeFile('helloworld.txt', 'Hello World!', function (err) {
   if (err) return console.log(err);
   ...
});
```

and check what's the problem is

Comment: in this console.log("something); is working perfectly. but res.json() not working. thats my problem.

Comment: So when the process shutdown, there is no error information printed in your server log ?  and BTW  thy to print err with forever -o out.log -e err.log your-node.js